# Typescript code generation using json-schema-to-typescript

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I am using [json-schema-to-typescript](https://github.com/bcherny/json-schema-to-typescript) in order to generate typescript types from json schema.

I am using the cli command:

```
json2ts  -i schema/ -o types/
```

inside the `schema` folder I have 2 files:

- elephant.json
- types.json

In types.json there is a definition of a `Dog`.
In elephant.json I declare array of `Dog`

I am expecting that the generated code code will have the field:

`dogs: Dog[]`

However the type `Dog` is not generated.
How can I make the code generator generate the `Dog` type and declare the array of dogs properly?
Below are my schema files and the generated typescript code:

### types.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "Dog": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 0
        },
        "breed": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "black",
            "brown",
            "white",
            "golden"
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "name",
        "age"
      ]
    },
    "Cat": {"type":  "object"}
  }
}
```

### elephant.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Elephant",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minimum": 3,
      "maximum": 12
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    },
    "gender": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["male", "female"]
    },
    "weight": {
      "description": "must be heavy..",
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "default": 30
    },
    "height": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "default": 100
    },
    "dogs": {
      "description": "Yes... every elephant needs a dog or two :-) ",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": { "$ref": "schema/types.json#/definitions/Dog" }
      },
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 2
    },
    "color": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["name", "age", "gender","height","dogs"]
}
```

### elephant.d.ts

```
/* eslint-disable */
/**
 * This file was automatically generated by json-schema-to-typescript.
 * DO NOT MODIFY IT BY HAND. Instead, modify the source JSONSchema file,
 * and run json-schema-to-typescript to regenerate this file.
 */

export interface Elephant {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: "male" | "female";
  /**
   * must be heavy..
   */
  weight?: number;
  height: number;
  /**
   * Yes... every elephant needs a dog or two :-)
   */
  dogs: {
    [k: string]: unknown;
  }[];
  color?: string;
}
```

### types.d.ts

```
/* eslint-disable */
/**
 * This file was automatically generated by json-schema-to-typescript.
 * DO NOT MODIFY IT BY HAND. Instead, modify the source JSONSchema file,
 * and run json-schema-to-typescript to regenerate this file.
 */

export interface Types {
  [k: string]: unknown;
}
```

## Update 1 - using "unreachableDefinitions" cli flag

Thanks to @Dimava I have added the cli flag `unreachableDefinitions` and now the "types" (Dog,Cat) are generated.
However the `Elephant` is still not using the `Dog` when it declare the dogs array.  It still looks like:

```
 dogs: {
    [k: string]: unknown;
  }[];
```

### types.d.ts

```
/**
 * This interface was referenced by `Types`'s JSON-Schema
 * via the `definition` "Dog".
 */
export interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  breed?: string;
  color?: "black" | "brown" | "white" | "golden";
}
/**
 * This interface was referenced by `Types`'s JSON-Schema
 * via the `definition` "Cat".
 */
export interface Cat {
  breed?: string;
}
```

## What is the code I am expecting to get?

Can this code generator generate such code?

```
 * This file was automatically generated by json-schema-to-typescript.
 * DO NOT MODIFY IT BY HAND. Instead, modify the source JSONSchema file,
 * and run json-schema-to-typescript to regenerate this file.
 */

import { Dog } from "./types";

 export interface Elephant {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: "male" | "female";
  /**
   * must be heavy..
   */
  weight?: number;
  height: number;
  /**
   * Yes... every elephant needs a dog or two :-)
   */
  dogs: Dog[];
  color?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable the `unreachableDefinitions` option

| unreachableDefinitions | boolean | false | Generates code for $defs that aren't referenced by the schema |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

https://github.com/bcherny/json-schema-to-typescript/issues/494

Comment: using `unreachableDefinitions` is a step in the right direction. It caused the Cat and Dog interfaces to be generated. However the dogs [] in Elephant still does not use the `Dog` definition. I will update the post accordingly . Thsnks.